# lobstr::obj_size maybe not calculating the right value

Tags: r

Could anybody explain me why obj_size is not giving the right value in this specific example?

```
> a<-c(1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L,8L,9L,10L)
> b<-1:10
> identical(a,b)
[1] TRUE

> object.size(a)
96 bytes
> object.size(b)
96 bytes
> obj_size(a)
96 B
> obj_size(b)
776 B
```

Comment: `obj_size() attempts to take into account the size of the environments associated with an object.` according to `?obj_size`

Comment: But shouldn't it do the same for the "a" object?

Comment: This probably has to do with the change in R 3.5 which states "Arithmetic sequences created by 1:n, seq_along, and the like now use compact internal representations via the ALTREP framework. Coercing integer and numeric vectors to character also now uses the ALTREP framework to defer the actual conversion until first use." So it's likely capturing additional information so it can delay expansion which is probably helpful when the list is much longer.